# Bypass fetch_feed cache

Tags: feed

I'm trying to bypass the cache used by fetch_feed, for specific users to force an update, by looking for the transient and deleting it before calling fetch_feed.

```
    if ( $this->bypass ) {
      $identifier = md5($this->feedUrl);
      $cacheKey = 'feed_' . $identifier;
      $cachedResult = get_transient($cacheKey);
      delete_transient($cacheKey);
    }

    $feedData = fetch_feed($this->feedUrl);
```

This however doesn't generate the correct transient key. They key in the database will be feed_2e798d9381cdbac2bb90151bf553c129 but this code is giving me feed_3f88b9c0e4a4ed755f0216b12b320fa5.

Is there a way to get the correct key from the url, or is there a method to delete the transient key via url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimplePie` does not necessarily use the exact feed URL that was passed to `fetch_feed()` – see [`SimplePie::get_cache_filename()`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-simplepie.php#L953-L984), but yes, WordPress adds the `feed_` prefix to the transient key.

So you can instead try using the [`wp_feed_options` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_feed_options/) to get the correct transient key and then delete the existing transient.

```php
$bypass = $this->bypass;

add_action(
    'wp_feed_options',
    function ( $feed ) use ( &$bypass ) {
        if ( $bypass ) {
            $cache_key = 'feed_' . $feed->get_cache_filename( $feed->feed_url );
            delete_transient( $cache_key );
            $bypass = false; // transient deleted, so reset this to the default
        }
    }
);

$feedData = fetch_feed( $this->feedUrl );
```

If you do **not** need to update the cached data, i.e. you just wanted to bypass *reading* from the cache, then you could simply use `function ( $feed ) use ( &$bypass ) { $feed->cache = ! $bypass; }`.